# Pad zeros if precision value less than scale

Tags: java, math, decimal, bigdecimal

If i divide 1.0f/2.0f , the value is 0.5 .

I wanted to have a precision value of 5 (0.50000). Used BigDecimal to set the scale to 5 but still the value is printed as 0.5

> BigDecimal  val = new BigDecimal(1.0f/2.0f);
>   BigDecimal tt =
>    val.setScale(5); 
>   System.out.println(tt.doubleValue);

How to set the scale and to make it 0.50000. I mean pad extra zero if the precision value is less than the scale

E.g in this case 1/2 is always 0.5 (precision is 1) and if i want a higher precision (say 5) , how do i achieve it

Please advise

Comment: `tt.doubleValue` You just converted `tt` back into a number without any particular formatting whatsoever.

Comment: it was late night for me so passed out . Apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print the BigDecimal

```
    BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal(1.0f/2.0f);
    BigDecimal tt = val.setScale(5); 
    System.out.println(tt);
```

or if you want to use a double, then your can use

```
    System.out.printf("%.5f%n", tt.doubleValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

use `DecimalFormat` :

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(1/2.0);
BigDecimal value = a.setScale(5, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
System.out.println(value);
```

The output is:

```
0.50000
```

Comment: where is your output coming from?  That is the problem that the OP is having

Comment: @ScaryWombat  `System.out.println(value);`

Comment: @ScaryWombat No, it's not the same. 1.  `1.0f/2.0f` is not necessary. 2. you dont have round mode, do you ?:)  We both have the correct answer